# c# how to get just date from sql server date column and display in textbox

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, date

when i get the date from the selected row and send to a text box in a different form it shows as 04/01/2017 00:00:00 but i just want the date.
this is how i select the row and get the date from the table.

```
public static string Dedob;

private void dgvEmployee_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = this.dgvEmployee.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Dename = row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
        Dedob =  row.Cells["DOB"].Value.ToString();
        Deaddress = row.Cells["ADDRESS"].Value.ToString();
        Deusername = row.Cells["USERNAME"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

then on form2

```
tbdob.Text = form1.Dedob;
```

then the textbox just shows 04/01/2017 00:00:00 how can i remove the time :/

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is DOB DateTime? If yes, have you tried using StringFormat?

Comment: `YourProperty.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: i have DOB in the table as Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateTime.ToShortDateString() works too.

((DateTime)row.Cells["DOB"].Value).ToShortDateString();

Comment: i tried all other ways and it kept telling me no overload for method or no change when i tried to convert . but this worked :D thanks for the help guys i no longer want to punch my screen.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    Dedob =  row.Cells["DOB"].Value.ToString("d MMM yyyy");
```

You can see more templates here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the row.Cells["DOB"].Value type is DateTime, than:

```
Dedob =  row.Cells["DOB"].Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```